# Profiling c++ using visual studio 2012 profiler

Tags: c++, profiling, profiler

I have a sln that have several c++ and c# projects
I want to profile one of my c++ projects, but for some reason I cannot find it under the list of available projects in the Performance Wizard
I can only see the c# projects

Anyone knows why?

thank you!
Ron

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  The cheaper editions don't have profiling.

Answer (score 1):

Which profiling mode are you using? If you are using sampling, the Performance Wizard will only show projects in the solution that compile to an executable. Note that the profiler will actually collect data for both C# and C++ assemblies if you have a mixed-mode application.

If you are using the Instrumentation profiling mode, the Performance Wizard should show you all projects in the solution so that you have an opportunity to decide which of them should be instrumented.